# How do I verify the checksum or hash of a downloaded file on the command line?

Tags: command-line, terminal, security, macos

If I have downloaded a file from the internet, and the source website has provided a checksum or hash (eg. SHA-256), how do I verify that the hash of the downloaded file matches the hash reported on the site?

For example, I’ve downloaded a file, and the website states that the SHA-256 hash for it is:

```
d9cd63f187db2daea1371289508c63a7a24c46316f15ac61f030a7d6ea423915
```

I do know how to create an SHA-256 hash of the downloaded file using:

```
shasum -a 256 /path/to/downloaded.pkg
```

However, I don’t want to do a manual, a.k.a. eyeball, check of the hash. Instead I want to compare the two hashes using a command like `diff`, preferably by executing a single command-line.

I'm running MacOS Catalina 10.15.4, and the shell is zsh.

Comment: `echo THAT_SUM filename | sha256sum -c`

Comment: On my macOS (Catalina 10.15.4), which runs zsh by default, the `sha256sum` command does not exist. Using `shasum -a 256 -c` is an alternative, however. Also, `shasum` expects a string of the form `"checksum  filename”`, where *two* spaces are required before filename.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `diff` to compare strings of the two hashes. Fortunately, this can be done in a single command-line entry as follows:

```
diff -is <(echo "d9cd63f187db2daea1371289508c63a7a24c46316f15ac61f030a7d6ea423915  /path/to/downloaded.pkg") <(shasum -a 256 /path/to/downloaded.pkg)
```

An important note: There must be *two* spaces between the hash in the first part of the term and the path to your downloaded file.

Portions of this answer exist in various places, but despite avid searching I haven’t found that it’s been put together anywhere. If there are better alternatives, I’d be happy to hear of them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sha256 checksum as example, if your downloaded file comes with a `<filename>.256` companion file, you can use `sha256sum -c <filename>.256` from within the containing directory. You should get the following output:

`<filename>: OK`